# magento onepage checkout problem

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I want to add shipping address, shipping methods and payment methods along with billing address step of onepage checkout in magento. please, give idea if any ... !

Comment: http://www.onestepcheckout.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant exactly tell you what to do , but i can lead you to where to go, the phtml of the onepage checkout on magento can be the place to manipulate how you want the chackout page to look like .

in the same time , there is the js file in the Skin folder , opcheckout.js , it is where the steps run by a prototype javascript code, which you can also edit how you want things to show.